# iOS Push Notifications - Developing from multiple computers

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I set up Push Notifications for my app and I'm using Parse.com to facilitate their operation.  Everything works well: I download the app onto my phone, send a push from Parse, and I get a notification.  Great.  Now I want another developer to get his device ready for action.  He plugs his phone into my computer, downloads the app, I send a notification, works great.  The provisioning profile contains his device so no problems.

However, when he downloads a copy of our app from the git repo onto his computer (+ downloads the provisioning profile and sets that up), downloads the app on his phone and then registers, push notifications don't work.  To be clear, it creates an installation entry in the Parse table with his newly created user but the deviceToken field is empty:

[image]

To put it simply, Parse creates an installation field with the deviceToken filled in if I download the app from my computer, but not anyone else's computer.  Might seem like a minor issue, but we often work in completely different locations so it could end up being a major one.

Comment: You need to make him part of your development team in iTunes so that he can sign the app with your developer team details; otherwise it will be associated with another developer profile and a different set of push certificates

Comment: Can I only do this if I have a company developer profile?  I have a single developer account and I don't see a People tab in Member Center to be able to add people to the team.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a single developer account (and not a company account), as you mentioned in the comment, you can simply send your certificates to the other developer's computer so that he'll sign the app with the same credentials, which should resolve your issue.

1. Goto to Keychain Access.
2. Find the relevant certificates (development/distribution certificates and possibly also the matching push development/distribution certificates) and press the small arrow to the left of the certificate name.
3. Select both the certificate and its matching key and right click to select the Export option.
4. Give the file some password that will be known to the other developer and send him these files.

When these files are opened by the other developer on his computer and added to his keychain access (simply by opening them and entering the right password), he should be able to use these files to sign the apps when installing them on his device, making it identical to the process performed from your computer. This should resolve the push issues. Good luck!

Comment: Hrmm...do I export them as .cert or .p12?  .cert doesn't ask to give the file some password, but that would seem like the way to go..  Anyway, I tried the .cert route, installed them on the other computer, XCode gave me a bunch of errors, I just went through and clicked "Fix Issue" a few times when prompted, push notifications still not working.  To be clear, I exported "Apple development iOS push services...." cert and "iPhone developer: [my name]"

Comment: When you exported the "iPhone developer: name" certificate, did you make sure to also export the key? Also, in XCode, did you use the same provisioning profile you use on your own computer? If you do all of these, XCode should have no problems with this and it should work exactly the same as it does on your computer. Also, there should be no "Fix Issue" use. When you selected that option, it may have changed the provisioning profile or certificate used to sign the app, and actually reverted to the original case.